# Product of $L^p$-convergent sequences are Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm working on showing:

If $\|f_n - f\|_p \to 0$ with $1≤p<\infty$ and $h_n \to h$ pointwise with $|h_n|<M$ for all $n$, then $\{f_nh_n\}$ is Cauchy in $L^p$

I've shown that $\|h_n-h\|_p \to 0$, but I'm having a hard time showing the product is Cauchy. I tried to manipulate the terms in the norm in additon to using Minkowski's inequality, but it hasn't worked thus far.

Comment: How did you determine that $\|h_n-h\|_p \to 0$? In general it isn't going to be true.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I showed that $M \in L^p$ and as $|h_n|≤M$ for all $n$ with $h_n \to h$ p.w., the $L^p$ dominated convergence theorem implies that $||h_n-h||_p\to 0$

Comment: What if the constant function $M$ isn't integrable?

Comment: @UmbertoP. You're right. The space could be infinite in measure. I'm actually trying to show this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888579/product-of-a-lp-convergent-sequence-and-pointwise-convergence-sequece I just need to show the Cauchy bit to conclude the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although $\|h_n - h\|_p$ may not converge to $0$, the dominated convergence theorem tells you that $\|f h_n  - fh\|_p \to 0$.  In particular $\{f h_n\}$ is Cauchy in the $L^p$ norm. Then apply the triangle inequality: for any $n$ and $m$ you have
\begin{align*} \|f_n h_n - f_m h_m\|_p &\le \|f_n h_n - f h_n\|_p + \|fh_n - fh_m\|_p + \|fh_m - f_m h_m\|_p \\
&\le K \|f_n - f\|_p + \|fh_n - fh_m\|_p + K \|f_m - f\|_p.
\end{align*}
All terms on the right tend to $0$ as $m,n \to \infty$.

---

On edit: you pointed out in the comments that you are actually trying to prove that $f_n h_n \to fh$ in $L^p$. You don't really need to go through Cauchy sequences to show this.  Using the fact that $\|fh_n - fh\|_p \to 0$ you have $$\|f_n h_n - fh\| \le \|f_n h_n - f h_n\|_p + \|fh_n - fh\|_p \le K \|f_n - f\|_p + \|fh_n - fh\|_p \to 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Being that $L_p$ is a complete space, there is $f\in L_p$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_p\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.

$$ |f_nh_n -fh|\leq |(f_n-f)h_n| + |fh_n-fh|\leq |f_n-f|M+|f||h_n-h|
$$

As $|f||h_n-h|\leq 2M|f|$ and $|f||h_n-h|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ a.s., $\|f(h-h_n)\|_p\rightarrow0$ by dominated convergence.
Consequently
$f_nh_n$ converges to $fh$ in $L_p$ and so, $\{f_nh_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.